# Make center aligned text prioritize bottom textline

Tags: css, center, centering

I was wondering whether it's possible to chose which text line centered text should prioritise.

Normally a sentence with `text-align:center` would look to wrap the text so that the first line will always be the widest of the two.

Is it possible to wrap the text to make the bottom line of text be the longest/widest?

For example a paragraph with 5 identical words would have 2 in top line of text and three in the bottom line.

Thanks in advance.

For code reference:

```
<p style="text-align:center;">word word word word word</p>
```

In certain widths when the sentence wraps the sentence would collapse like this:

```
word word word
word word
```

I'd like it to collapse like this:

```
word word
word word word
```

I'm aware i can wrap the sentence in different p, span or whatever elements. I'm just curious as the whether there is a css solution to this kind of word wrapping or not.

Comment: Try to post some code if you can.

Comment: Like write on a pyramid shape ?

Comment: Yeah like a pyramid, sorry if it's explained poorly.

Comment: I updated my question with some code showing what i mean :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, in my opinion, is to use two separate `<p>` tags (or whatever text element you choose) and adjust the horizontal padding of each independently.

For example, the markup would be:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
p:first-of-type {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 32px;
}

p:last-of-type {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 16px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's the obvious solution i guess. It's for user generated content, however, so I can't control where they separate the p tags. It's not a big issue at all if there is no css solution for it. I just got curious :)

Comment: You can try using the `:first-line` pseudo-element to target the first line rendered by the browser.